# Visual Studio - Prevent F11 from starting the debugger?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to prevent Visual studio to start the debugger when pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>? I often press it by mistake when I want to actually press <kbd>F12</kbd>.
I do not want to loose the functionality of Step-into which <kbd>F11</kbd> provides but it is annoying when it starts the application.

Comment: I think I'll tear off that key one day.

Comment: It's truly an anti-feature; a booby trap even

Comment: @vorou I tore off my insert key. After a couple years, I realized that I really have never wanted to use that key.

Answer (score 7):

This is for VS 2010, but it should be similar for others.

In Tools->Options, open Keyboard under Environment.  Look up the command Debug.StepInfo.  You can remove the default shortcut (F11 (Global)) and then just use the toolbar button to step into, or right click and "Step into specific"--which is what I do since it keeps the debugger from diving into STL functions if they're part of a line of code (as an example).

Answer (score 5):

A hack-around that I use is to use the cancel build command after I accidentally hit <kbd>F11</kbd>. The default shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>pause/break</kbd>.

This doesn't stop <kbd>F11</kbd> starting a build, but should stop it from running your program.

Comment: Awesome when your keyboard has no dedicated Pause/Break key.

Comment: you should be able to remap this if you don't have one. Build.cancel keyboard shortcut is configurable :)

Comment: Yes, I ended up remapping to Ctrl + F6.

Answer (score 5):

Updated to link to [latest Tweaks 2022](https://www.vsixgallery.com/extension/0c8bd9fa-77d5-4563-ab57-9e01608c3d05). Also see the comment below.

[This](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/960671/please-provide-a-way-to-disable-f10f11-until-debug.html) is the suggestion on Microsoft's VS Community forum. Tweaks was built by none less than VS project manager Mads Kristensen himself and directly fixes this issue, among many other VS annoyances. [Free extension Tweaks](https://www.vsixgallery.com/extension/0c8bd9fa-77d5-4563-ab57-9e01608c3d04):

> Don't start debug on F10/F11 Inspired by the suggestion Please provide
> a way to disable F10/F11 until debug mode is entered.
>
> F10 (Step Over) and F11 (Step Into) are two commands people often hit
> by accident. That starts a new debugging session and that can be
> annoying if you didn't mean for that to happen. They should only take
> effect during a debug session.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: Tweaks was built by none less than VS project manager Mads Kristensen himself and directly fixes this issue, among many other VS annoyances. A version of [tweaks for VS2022](https://www.vsixgallery.com/extension/0c8bd9fa-77d5-4563-ab57-9e01608c3d05) is available as well!

Comment: @SeanWerkema thanks I didn't know he separate it by years. Why would he do that lol. I updated the answer to link to the latest version.

Comment: It's probably because the extension pokes heavily at the internals of Visual Studio itself, internals that likely change a lot between versions. I would bet the VS2022 version doesn't work on VS2019 and likely vice-versa.

Answer (score -2):

Install Resharper and Change the Key Short Settings

Comment: Why use an external tool to change the keyboard short cuts when you can do it natively inside VS?

Comment: @cvanbrederode If VS can't do it (as you don't want to disable F11 while debugging) then you'll have to.

Comment: The OP actually does want to disable F11 for debugging.  Which is fine, since the Step-Into function can still be selected from the tool bar and from the menu.

Comment: @cvanbrederode: I disagree, the OP only wants to stop F11 starting a new debug session while editing code and specifically when he intended to use F12 for source code navigation. On fiddly laptop keyboards with half height function keys the F12/F11 miskey this is a common problem.

Comment: @camelCase  F11 is bound to the StepInto command.  Pressing it while not debugging automatically starts a debug session.  Same thing with F10 (step over).  There's no support to have the shortcut work while debugging, but not while editing (and not debugging).